# Excel jar poi 3.13 HTC not reading file

Tags: android, apache-poi

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcw34.jpg)

I want to read excel file in Maps for loading districts in Samsung j5  device is working perfectly without error
when i start using HTC 516 as emulator (real device) then POI-3.13-Library start throwing this error i may not able to fix the error my excel file is simple have two columns please suggest me better solution for problem

```
04-22 16:07:58.280 5264-5264/kyp.E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'org.apache.poi.hpsf.MutablePropertySet', referenced from method org.apache.poi.POIDocument.writePropertySet
04-22 16:07:58.280 5264-5264/kyp.W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 8728 (Lorg/apache/poi/hpsf/MutablePropertySet;) in Lorg/apache/poi/POIDocument;
04-22 16:07:58.280 5264-5264/kyp.D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
04-22 16:07:58.280 5264-5264/kyp.W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve exception class 8737 (Lorg/apache/poi/hpsf/WritingNotSupportedException;)
04-22 16:07:58.280 5264-5264/kyp.W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x44
04-22 16:07:58.280 5264-5264/kyp.W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejected Lorg/apache/poi/POIDocument;.writePropertySet (Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/poi/hpsf/PropertySet;Lorg/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/NPOIFSFileSystem;)V
04-22 16:07:58.280 5264-5264/kyp.W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0044
04-22 16:07:58.280 5264-5264/kyp.W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejected Lorg/apache/poi/POIDocument;.writePropertySet (Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/poi/hpsf/PropertySet;Lorg/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/NPOIFSFileSystem;)V
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.W/dalvikvm: Verifier rejected class Lorg/apache/poi/POIDocument;
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x420048b0)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.VerifyError: org/apache/poi/POIDocument
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.E/AndroidRuntime:     at kyp..MapsActivity.readexcel(MapsActivity.java:788)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.E/AndroidRuntime:     at kyp..MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:110)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp. E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp. E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp. E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp. E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-22 16:07:58.290 5264-5264/kyp.E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 16:08:00.310 5264-5354/kyp.D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 569K, 13% free 4757K/5456K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
```

Comment: Did you try [following the advice in the Apache POI FAQ entry for could not find method or class](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)? If not, why not, and what happens when you do? If yes, what did that report and did that help you solve it?

Comment: Can you post which exact version of Android is running on those two devices?

Comment: On Samsung J5 android version 5.1.1 and htc 4.3

Comment: No advice in Apache found for this type of problem because its verify error for one device but ok for other device.

Comment: Please help me in matter @Gagravarr

Comment: Please help me in matter @centic

Comment: So it is likely related to the version of Android, there were major changes in 5.x, the only help/advice that I can give is to try to stick to one version of Android and if you are going to use 5.x then take a look at https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx for a way to use POI fully on Android.

Comment: But what i use if want to run my app on HTC 4.3 which poi in MAPSACTIVITY @centic Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is an older project that should work with Android 4, I have summarized my response in a voteable-answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely related to the version of Android, there were major changes in 5.x.

If you are going to use 5.x then take a look at https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx for a way to use POI fully on Android.

If you need Android 4.x support, then please refer to https://github.com/andruhon/AndroidReadXLSX

Furthermore there is an early version of another approach at https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/ which allows to build a single jar for Apache POI with all the required dependencies. This one likely also required Android 5.x or newer due to the large size of the jar-file.

Comment: In MAPSACTIVITY if i want to use EXCEL jar ANDROID 4.x please help me given solution is not working @centic

Comment: Why Htc not supporting POI

Comment: How to know from which version of andorid or API poi library is supported

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a lot of experience I only know those projects and they promise to do what you need.